# Deploying BPEL process on the Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, wso2, bpel, apache-ode, business-process

Usually we deploy BPEL business processes on Apache ODE or WSO2 BPS Server included in Tomcat server, can I deploy a business process on Google App Engine's Web Server? Actually I haven't any idea about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot more to running a BPEL process than it seems. You would not deploy the BPEL process, you would deploy Apache ODE to Google App Engine.

Unfortunately, last I checked App Engine has stringent restrictions on the number of threads a program can spawn, making Apache ODE unusable (see [0](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/)(their doc)):

> The secured "sandbox" environment isolates your application for service and security. It ensures that apps can only perform actions that do not interfere with the performance and scalability of other apps. For instance, an app cannot spawn threads in some ways, write data to the local file system or make arbitrary network connections. An app also cannot use JNI or other native code. The JVM can execute any Java bytecode that operates within the sandbox restrictions.

Comment: This is helpful @Antonie Toulme :) I have another question, if any application can't spawn threads, so is there another way to run business processes on Google App Engine?

Comment: I don't have absolute proof either way. But you know what, AWS or other clouds can do the job. Or maybe try Heroku could. I would try other places rather than make this fit their app engine requirements.

Comment: @Antonie Toulme, Sorry I totally forgot to accept your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

you can't. See Google app engine's documentation.

[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ 
[2] https://developers.google.com/search/results?q=BPEL&p=%2Fappengine

Comment: It seems that you didn't understand my question, I mean, I want to combine some WSDL-based web services(service composition--->create a BPEL Process) and then run the composite servcice's .WSDL file, Can I do that via Google App Engine?